# How to downgrade IntelliJ to older version

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I have intelliJ 12 30day free software installed with entire project setup and running ; now I have a license received from my company and it is not allowing to register; then realised it is a license of intelliJ 11 version; please lemme know steps to downgrade to intelliJ 11.   Like running a patch or what is the solution?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Download and install the old version from [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).

Another option is to use the [JetBrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/). It allows to install multiple IDE versions, perform rollbacks if needed, applies updates to the IDE and plug-ins, etc.

Comment: setting up entire project, maven, + other plugins, server configuration; it's a pain; i am just wondering if there is any easier option than going through all this again.

Comment: File | Export Settings / File Import Settings. Note that settings from the new version may break something in the older version.

Comment: How does one do rollbacks in Toolbox 1.17 (2020)?

Comment: @isherwood the same: https://i.imgur.com/AiMas0t.png

Comment: Odd. That option isn't available for me. Maybe it's version-dependent. It states that my version was installed manually, which is odd since it's been updated automatically many times.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks a lot. It may be useful in case a problem with a latest version. On the other hand, do you have any idea regarding to boosting performance on IntelliJ IDEA besides update/ downgrade?

Comment: @Maxwell Refer to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235 if you have performance issues.

Comment: Older version of Intellij Idea 2019 shows the windows zip is just 64kB

Answer (score 7):

My operating System is Ubuntu 18.04
**I downgraded my Idea community edition version 2020.3 to 2020.2 because it was causing so much lombok issues** by using the following steps:
**Step 1** : open ubuntu software search idea community
click on channel version select version you wish to install and it will downgrade your version with all settings restored.
if you dont want previous settings then just clean uninstall idea
[image]

Comment: Do I have to do something after selecting the proper channel. Mine seems to do nothing.

Comment: there are two options launch and remove at the top left you can either click on launch or if the launch label changes to install after changing your channel then click on install that will install the channel you selected

Comment: I came to this answer as I'm also having problems with springboot+generated sources+lombok / java11 openjdk + IntellliJ 2020.3.1 -> classes are not recognised etc. Hope downgrading to 2020.2.4 helps...

Comment: This week Intellij has been updated to 2021.1. I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 and I guess snap sneakily auto-updated my Intellij this morning. It happened to not open anymore... I downgraded the version back to 2020.3 as @SumedhDeshpande suggested and it worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov how did you downgrade exactly? 
On the top I only have a remove button and nothing happens when I'm clicking on the vesion number at the bottom

Comment: @emul after you open IDEA page in Store there's a folding menu called "Source" at the top right corner (a little bit above the app rating; to the left of "Minimize"-"Restore Down"-"Close" window buttons). It suggests a listing of all available versions and I chose 2020.3/stable.